# Is application variable will be common for both classic asp and asp.net?

Tags: application-state

Our application is combination of classic asp and asp.net. Can we access same  application variable in classic asp which is defined in asp.net .

Comment: You can have .NET web application with .asp files in it. What do you mean by state ? Session or some emulation of shared static variables ?

Comment: state here means, application state. If i define an application variable in asp.net, can i use that in classic asp.

Answer (score 4):

No, if the classic asp files are getting run separate from the asp.net web application, they will run in different address space and will not share the application or session context.

Comment: Is application state context can be shared if classic asp files are running on asp.net web application? @Lucas Holt

Comment: They're not running on the same "web application" because the handlers for .asp and .aspx are different in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

No, I think they will run in a different address space and will not share the application or session context. 
You can use the given link to understand How to Share Session State Between Classic ASP and ASP.NET: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479313.aspx